# Is there a way to stop MS Word 2013 from inserting a tab when I double click to the right of a blank paragraph

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, tabs, text-formatting

When I double click to the right of a pragraph mark of an empty paragraph, Word inserts a tab.  Word  will also sometimes insert a tab in an empty paragraph if I click and drag to select text and I stop to the right of a blank paragraph mark.  Is there any way to stop this annoying (and buggy) behavior?  Deselecting "Set left- and first-indent with tabs and backspaces" in the "Autoformat as you type" tab of the Autocorrect options has no apparent effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the **Enable click and type** check box is selected on the **Advanced** tab in Word Options, that would cause the tab when you click to the right of the paragraph mark. However, I've never heard of this inserting a tab during a drag operation. It doesn't do that for me, at any rate (but I'm also using Word 2016, not 2013).

Comment: Disabling the **Enable click and type** solves both issues completely.  The insertion of a tab when I drag to select text and end the drag to the right of a blank paragraph mark has been annoying me for years.  Thanks!!