# Prevent insertion of tab when selecting across empty paragraph

Tags: windows

When using Word, Outlook email or Outlook Journal, I often use the mouse to select swaths of text.  In the course of selecting the text, When pointer crosses an empty paragraph, an unwanted tab character is suddenly inserted in the empty paragraph.  This happens in Windows 7.

Is this a bug?  How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

For Word, I found [an answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1144026/is-there-a-way-to-stop-ms-word-2013-from-inserting-a-tab-when-i-double-click-to). One has to disable `Click and type` in Word. The behaviour will then be fixed both in Word and Outlook. In Word 2013, one gets to the `Click and type` checkbox via `File->Options->Advanced`. It is about 3 quarters of the way down the very first section ("Editing options").

The above only affects Outlook if Word stays open.  However, I eventually found a `Click and type` switch in Outlook which fixes the behaviour in email compositions even when Word is closed.  I was working with Office 2010 when I found it: `Outlook->Mail->File->Options->Mail->EditorOptions->Advanced->EditorOptions->EnableClickAndType`